# Persisting Objects while Still Preserving Loose Coupling

Tags: c, persistence, loose-coupling, cohesion

I working on a project in a microcontroller and I need to persist some settings.  Pretend this is an iPod.  I need to save various settings like `CurrentSongPlaying`, `CurrentVolume`, etc. so that when I turn on again I can restore those settings.  The trouble I'm running into is that makes sense to store all my Non-Volatile Settings in a single struct that I can serialize/de-serialize from memory but I can't find a way to make that happen without the class doing the serialization/de-serialization from non-volatile memory including every class that contains a setting that will need to be saved for size/type information.  Is there some sort of design pattern that will allow me to persist all these settings to memory without having to know about what I'm saving?

Comment: Can you show an example, pseudo-code at the very least, of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you not move to C++?   Inheritance/polymorphism makes all this kind of stuff much easier!

Comment: Looks like you just need an associative array.

Comment: @netcoder - That looks to be exactly what I need, you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). An associative array (or map) is a container that allows you to map different values to unique keys. It can have a fixed or dynamic size depending on the implementation. Coupled with a proper serialization mechanism, it allows you to save and restore its state without having to know its content in advance.

However, C does not provide this data structure out-of-the-box. [Look at this question for a few implementations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864453/associative-arrays-in-c) The most common implementation is the [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), also called a hash map.

Answer (score 0):

OOP and classes are not easy to implement in C.

If using C is a must, I would write the struct to file.

Then I would read them and parse them during initialization upon reboot.

You can think of this as serializing your structs yourself.

Comment: That's the approach I suggested in my question, the problem is that I have to include all the other "classes" (header files) for any "object" (type) that I want to serialize so the struct can know about them. How do I avoid the "class" that does the writing/reading having to include every file that contains an "object" I would like to save in memory.