# Runtime initialization of structure member in C ( member name decided at run )

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm wondering for a solution to the below problem. Please help.

Problem:

```
struct s{
int a;
int b;
}st;
```

I want a function to initialize the values at runtime. The problem is that I want to make it generic, so I want to pass the member name as input to the function and get it initialized.

```
fun_init(char* mem, int val)
{
  // Find offset of the member variable in struct 'st'
  // Assign the value
}
```

One straight solution is to use string comparision on the member name. But if I happen to add some extra variables at a later time, I'll have to modify the function, which I don't want.
Hope I was able to frame the ques clearly.

Thanks

Comment: C names don't exist at run-time. The compiled code doesn't need them.

Comment: Use a `union` perhaps...

Comment: If you only need this for one or two structures, you could use a code generator to set up the appropriate data structures or generate suitable code for accessing the fields.  Of course this has the usual issues associated with code generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void fun_init(int *storage, int val) {
    *storage = val;
}
void something_else(void) {
    struct s {
        int a;
        int b;
    } st;
    fun_init(&st.a, 42);
}
```

However, if you need to dynamically determine the key name, you are doing something wrong. If you need to store key/value pairs, perhaps you would be [interested in the hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

C does not provide a way to find a symbol by name. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353022/reflection-support-in-c) for more information.

The simplest solution here is to use an [associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864453/associative-arrays-in-c).

[Read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-a-mixed-data-type-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array) if you need to mix value-types. (In your example, all value types are int, so you might not need this.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to initialize struct from either user input or persistency.

A solution involves creating an associative array as mentioned by @Domi.

The array is filled with key/value pairs such as  (const char*, unsigned).
The key is the name of struct member and the value is the offset from the start of the struct.
Each struct will need to have a function that initializes the above array. You can get an offset to a member via the `offsetof` macro.

This will **NOT** work with structs that have bit fields (sub byte named members).