# Associative array in C

Tags: php, c, associative-array

In `php` I can crate a `associative array` like

```
$my_arr = array('a' => 'Apple', 'b' => 'Ball', 'c' => 'Cat');
```

Is it possible to create a `associative array` in `C`

You may think it is duplicate question for [Associative arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864453/associative-arrays-in-c) But I can't found what I want.

Comment: If you need C++ solution then you can use `map`.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks. But I want to get solution in c

Comment: C or C++? There's a difference.

Comment: @Jefffrey Yes. C is procedure oriented programming language and C++ is object oriented language.

Comment: It is reasonable simple to implement a hash table in C, especially if the size is known in advance, since most of the code is related to the dynamic resizing the table.

Comment: http://judy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain you want a solution in C or C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no prebuilt utility in standard C to accomplish this task. Your best shot is to try to implement a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) (or an [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for non ordered associative containers) on your own.

If you have the luck to work with C++, on the other hand, you can use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). Here's an example for `std::map`:

```
std::map<char, std::string> map;
map['a'] = "Apple";
map['b'] = "Ball";
map['c'] = "Cat";
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35cce1317ff1d6a9)

Comment: The question is asking for an associative array in C not C++, not a valid answer

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer, How is "There's no prebuilt utility in standard C to accomplish this task." not a valid answer exactly?

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer, also, the question was [initially tagged with C++ as well](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22908516/1).

Comment: 1- I see a `C` tag. 2- `C++` tag was removed. 3- The question asks `Is it possible to create a associative array in C`. 4- the question state that his question is not a duplicate of another question asking for an associative array in C.

Comment: "How is "There's no prebuilt utility in standard C to accomplish this task." not a valid answer exactly?" That should've been a comment, not an answer

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Unfortunately for you, "there's no standard utility in C to accomplish this task. Your best bet is to try implementing a red-black tree on your own" is a perfectly valid answer to the question "Is it possible to create a associative array in C?".

Comment: You can also implement a hash table instead of a red-black tree if you don't care about the order of the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Really robust and simple way to do it is to have a struct with key and value fields. Lets call it pair (name derived from C++ class of the same name and purpose). Also you should think of the types you want have for the pair fields. I give an example as char to string values as your php example. But in order to use different types you must use void*, but that will result in a very complicated and probably bug prone implementation.

Something like

```
struct
{
    char key;
    char* value;
}pair;

struct pair map[size];

pair assocation;
assocation.key = 'a';
assocation.value = "Apple"; // Be sure to allocate the C strings so that you do not introduce memory leak or data corruption, same for void*. This here is just an hack.

map[0] = assocation;  

// Later in your algorithms and parsers you just access it as an value in array.  
pair aPair = map[1];
char aKey = aPair.key;
char* aValue = aPair.value;
```

When you want a linked list like associative array, then add one more field to a struct:

```
void* nextPair;
```

With that you can allocate you key-value pairs everywhere and do not need to contain them in a single array.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, C is too low-level to have a built-in associative array type. Probably the closest you can get to it is to use a third party library such as http://svn.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/sys/tree.h, documented in http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tree  or http://ivoras.sharanet.org/freebsd/usetree.html.

Comment: can you provide an example how it can be used as an associative array ?