# Figuring out how to set up memory for MIPS simulator

Tags: c, mips

I'm writing a MIPS simulator in C++.  It takes in a text file in hex, and needs to output the register contents and the decoded instruction after every instruction. So I convert the hex file to binary to grab the opcodes, rs, rt, rd, funct, and sham field so I can figure out what instruction it is.

I'm stuck because I've come the SW and LW instructions and I'm not sure how to handle simulating the memory.  I have my registers in an array[0-31] and as well as my instructions[whatever number of instructions read in], and words[whatever number or words read in].

But I'm not sure how to simulate LW and SW... I know how to encode/decode them, but the memory part (along with the offset) is throwing me off.  Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well, words in MIPS are 32 bits so why not just an array of `int32_t`? Then LW and SW become reading and writing to array indices respectively.

Comment: @Quirliom So if I just declared an array of int32_t with a size of say 4000, whenever i have an instruction that is like SW      $v0,8($gp) it would just save it at the "address" of $gp in the array index 8?

Comment: Have an array of `int_32t`s. When you get a `SW $v0,8($gp)` store the value of v0 at the index `$gp + 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the contents are dense and/or speed is of the essence, and you have plenty of memory in the environment you're simulating in, you could just use a big honkin' array (just like you're doing with the registers - but bigger).

If the contents are sparse, and/or you don't have a boatload of memory in the environment in which you're running the simulator, and speed is less significant than space, you could use an associative array.

This question references a couple of C libraries for associative arrays:

[Associative arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864453/associative-arrays-in-c)

Comment: If you want to see how someone else has done it, you could take a look at Nachos: http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tom/nachos/, in particular Machine::ReadMem in code/machine/translate.cc and Machine::OneInstruction (the cases for OP_LW and OP_SW), in mipssim.cc

Comment: I have a lot of memory, so I'm leaning toward a big array.  I guess I'm just a little confused.  If I "store" say $s1 into memory with offset 0, it would store it in the first index right?  What if I then need to store $s2 into memory with offset 0 as well, won't that overwrite the first?