# Does C support key-value pair data structure?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have following data table :

[image]

And I want to organize it in C data structure ,and accessing by :

Example :

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
printf("%d",arr["Peter"]["Read"]) ; //1 
printf("%d",arr["Jonathan"]["Execute"]) ; //0
```

or modify it :

```
arr["Marry"]["Write"] = TRUE ;
```

Is this impossible in C ?

.//Update 
I think it's difference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864453/associative-arrays-in-c) because my question about accessing value via 2 key

Comment: an array of a structure with 2-D array.

Comment: and some `#define`s.

Comment: Why a `struct`? @SouravGhosh

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to make up a syntax and then ask if you can coerce the language into making it work. It's equivalent to saying, "I want to say 'myxlypik moonlop' and have it mean something in English." Sure, you could probably find some way to make those exact things mean something in that language, but WHY? That's not how you use a language. You decide what you want to say, then you figure out how to say it in the language.

Comment: @alk Just to have a user-defined data type, later if we want to expand, in that case, it can come handy. :)